# IdentityServer4 - protecting WebAPI actions

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I've successfully integrated my .net Core WebAPI with IdentityServer4 where a client is able to request a token and send back via auth. header when calling the controller and able to successfully authorize.
***However, I do have a question around fined grained authorization.***

When inserting a new ApiResource, I am also adding scopes (ex. app.api1.read, app.api2.read, etc..) and the client has access to the scopes (app.api1.read and app.api2.read). When the client calls app.api1, they can pass either scopes app.ap1.read or app.api2.read and both would be authorized successfully. Ideally, I would want the client to pass scope for api1 (ex. app.api1.read) and if they pass scope for api2 it should not be authorized.

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    // base-address of your identityserver
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44393";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });
```

**TestController.cs**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : Controller
{
```

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to leverage Auth Policies.  Take a look at this Auth0 article.  Obviously it's designed for Auth0, but it should equally apply to IS4 (same underlying tech).  You can setup policies that all fine-grain auth by scope.  https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization

Comment: That' exactly what I was looking for and works like a charm. Thank you so much Bryan. You're a lifesaver :)